# How to feed my C Program in Terminal files for it to sequentially display?

Tags: c, command-line, terminal

I have created a program that sequentially displays on screen the contents of all of the files listed in the command line.

However, when I run it in terminal I can't actually get it to open any files I try to "feed" it.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Here is an example of what I'm typing into Terminal on my mac:

`"John_Smith-MacBook:Desktop smith_j$ "/Users/smith_j/Desktop/Question 3-28-13 5.10               PM/usr/local/bin/Question" helloworld.txt`

`Could not open file helloworld.txt for input"`

This is the first day I've ever used Terminal so forgive me if the answer is very easy.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int byte;
    FILE * source;
    int filect;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s filename[s]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (filect = 1; filect < argc; filect++)
    {
        if ((source = fopen(argv[filect], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file %s for input\n", argv[filect]);
            continue;
        }
        while ((byte = getc(source)) != EOF)
        {
            putchar(byte);
        }
        if (fclose(source) != 0)
            printf("Could not close file %s\n", argv[1]);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your diagnostic after `fclose()` should reference `argv[filect]`, not `argv[1]`.  Errors should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  You've read the character into an `int` — that's good and avoids a collection of problems.  Is there actually a file `helloworld.txt` in the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the value of `errno` [probably with `perror()` ] so you know why it is failing to open.

Simple example:

```
perror("fopen failed:");
printf("errno = %d.\n", errno);
```

It will prefix the text version of the errno condition (library supplied) with "fopen Failed: ", then give the specific errno value.

The text of your command line above looks suspect, check to see if it is correct.  Better yet, try calling your program with a simpler command line, for example, one file in the current directory with your binary.

Instead of all the long pathnames, put both the binary program and the data file in the same directory together.  Then, from that location just do `./myprog filename.txt`

That will have less chance of a typo interfering with execution.

Comment: Randy, I'm not familiar with that function. How would I use it?

Comment: I checked the text, it is correct. I just opened another program I made and it worked fine - I was able to feed it strings. Not sure what's wrong here. I'm supposed to be able to give it files to open and display, but it won't accept them

Comment: So what is the reason it is failing?  When a function fails and gives an error value, either in the return, or by setting errno, always to check to see why.

Comment: Randy, I got it. I'm not sure what was wrong. Thanks for your help. I'll delete this now.

Comment: No need to delete it.  Your program seems to work here, so I was fairly sure it was an issue with the command line arguments.